# List structure for a column?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

Consider that I have one table in mysql that stores info about users:
Id, email, phone, fname, lname, etc.

Each user can have some other user in his contact list, so I thought of storing a mapping between id of user and his contact user=> this would result in n rows in case user has n contacts, so I thought of minimizing by entering list of contact ids to each Id.

This way each id will have one row with a list of ids.
Question is how would I add new id to the list or remove id which appears in the middle of the ids list.

I guest there is no list structure for a column, and list will appear as a long string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your first thought was correct. Don't put lists in a column. Queries that use this column can't be indexed.

Comment: You are trying to treat a sql database like a nosql database. In theory, it doesn't matter that you have X rows. And as pointed out above, it can't be indexes, so if you allow the deletion of users, how are you going to find the ones that have been added as contacts? If you want to build apps in this style, move to mongo or dynamo or some other document style db.